# What methods do you know for the geting data type in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, object, types

For example I have a some code:

```
({}).toString.call(new Date()); // "[object Date]"
```

anybody knows, another methods how to check type?
(I wanna to receive only `date` type without object)

Comment: did you tried `typeof`?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz , typeof return only object, I need a `date`

Comment: If you already know it is an `object` type, you can use `instanceof` or check the constructor function.

Comment: @user268396 you are not right, `instanceof` we can use if we know type, in this case is better to use `variable.constructor.name`

Comment: Keep in mind that JavaScript is very dynamic, so any solution you find is probably not 100% reliable, meaning that only because something returns a specific value it may not be what you expect. Case in point: `({}).toString.call({[Symbol.toStringTag]: 'Date'})`.

Comment: Please note that the name of an object's constructor is a totally different concept from [*Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values). Values have a Type (number, string, object, etc.), all objects are type object, unless they're also functions, in which case they are type function.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to check types the way you are asking to is using the method you already posted. You can make it a little bit easier though.

```js
function type(value) {
  const tag = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
  return tag.slice(8, -1);
}

console.log(type(new Date()));
console.log(type(5));
console.log(type(function() {}));
```

Comment: This is a good way to go about it, but the function should not be called "Type". By convention, function names starting with a capital letter denote constructors, and [*Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values) is a totally different concept to constructor name (which is more akin to "class", but that name should probably be avoided too).